# Разные способы инициализации членов класса

Tags: c++, конструктор, инициализация

Совсем запутался. Объясните, пожалуйста, какой тип инициализации будет для членов класса `A` в 3 указанных случаях и какие значения они будут принимать:

```
#include <vector>


struct A {
    A() = default;

    A(int, int) {}

    int a;
    int b{};
    int c = {};
    int d{42};

    std::vector<int> va;
    std::vector<int> vb{};
    std::vector<int> vc = {};
};


int main() {
    A sa;      // 1
    A sb{};    // 2
    A sc = {}; // 3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1 - инициализация по умолчанию (default initialization). Она будет выполняться путем вызова конструктора `A::A()`, который примет во внимание указанные вами умолчательные инициализаторы для полей класса. Для поля `va` он вызовет конструктор по умолчанию, а поле `a` оставит неинициализированным.

Варианты 2 и 3 одинаковы - это инициализация списком (list initialization). Она в данном случае приведет к value-инициализации. Так как конструктор по умолчанию класса `A` не является *предоставленным пользователем*, value-инициализация не будет вызывать конструктор класса `A`, а будет инициализировать поля этого класса индивидуально. Она тоже примет во внимание указанные вами умолчательные инициализаторы для полей класса. Те поля, для которых не указано инициализатора, будут подвергнуты default initialization, включая поле `a`.

Таким образом поля класса будут принимать те значения, которые вы указали при помощи умолчательных инициализаторов в определении класса. Для поля `va` инициализатор не указан, но так так у класса `std::vector<int>` есть явно определенный конструктор по умолчанию, то инициализация поля `va` будет выполнена именно им.

Единственное поле, значение которого зависит от внешнего инициализатора - это поле `a`. В случае 1 это поле останется неинциализированным. В случаях 2 и 3 это поле будет инициализировано нулем.

---

Важной деталью является то, что прямо в определений класса вы определили конструктор по умолчанию как defaulted. Такой конструктор по умолчанию не считается *предоставленным пользователем*. Именно по этой причине value-инициализация такого класса не использует такой конструктор по умолчанию, а самостоятельно напрямую инициализирует индивидуальные поля.

А если бы вы определили конструктор `A::A()` как defaulted за пределами определения класса

```
struct A {
    A();
    ...
};

A::A() = default;
```

то такой конструктор по умолчанию считался бы *предоставленным пользователем*. В такой ситуации value-инициализация просто вызывала бы `A::A()` и никакой функциональной разницы между вариантами 1, 2 и 3 не было бы. То есть во всех трех вариантах поле `a` осталось бы неинициализированным.

Comment: А внутри самого класса во всех 3 случаях: `a,va` - `default initialization`, `b,c,d,vb,vc` - `value initialization`?

Comment: Или нельзя рассматривать такую инициализацию отдельно от инициализации enclosed класса?

Comment: @tom: Когда инициализатор указан явно - то да. А если явного инициализатора не указано, то инициализацией таких полей заведует "внешний процесс" (например, конструктор) и все зависит от него. Обратите внимание на поле `a`. Нельзя сразу сказать, что ему приписана default инициализация. В рамках value-инициализации всего класса - да. В рамках default-инициализации всего класса - нет.